# Sort file with port/interface numbers

Tags: bash

I have a list with random port numbers.

```
cat port.txt   
Fa0/2
Fa0/26 
Fa0/3 
Fa0/10 
Fa0/1
```

How to sort theme sequential order, so output will be

```
Fa0/1
Fa0/2
Fa0/3
Fa0/10 
etc
```

Thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sort -t/ -k2,2n inputfile
```

For your input, it'd produce:

```
Fa0/1
Fa0/2
Fa0/3
Fa0/10
Fa0/26
```